# Is there a way to select fields that are grayed out on the Socrata web client?

Tags: socrata

I am attempting to get the compared_to_national column for the readmission data located at [Data.Medicare.gov](https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Readmissions-Complications-and-Deaths-Hospital/7xux-kdpw)
This column is grayed out on the web interface making me think that it is a computed field or a join with another table.

$ curl https://data.medicare.gov/resource/7xux-kdpw? | grep national

shows that this value is not being returned at all even when everything is selected. Am I missing something here or is this data just not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but maybe I can still help out.

The greyed out values are data that was incompatible with the selected datatype at import time. In the case of [Readmissions Complications and Deaths - Hospital](https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Readmissions-Complications-and-Deaths-Hospital/7xux-kdpw?), that's textual data that the data owner attempted to import into a Numeric column type.

Unfortunately it isn't queryable, but I'll let the account manager for CMS know so that hopefully they can have that fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel a little silly for asking the question but it is great to see I wasn't messing up something trivial on my side again.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help, at least a little.